Media query doesn't work after deployment with Tailwind CSS and NextJS
Hello I'm using NextJS and Tailwind CSS for my application. There are no problems when running locally however, when I deploy the application to Vercel the media query is not taking effect. It appears to be ignored. Thanks a lot
     <div className="flex grow items-center justify-end sm:hidden mobile">
          <PopoverButton className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500 openmenu">
            {({ open }) => (
              <>
                <span className="sr-only">
                  {open ? "Close Menu" : "Open Menu"}
                </span>
                {open ? (
                  <XMarkIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                ) : (
                  <Bars3Icon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                )}
              </>
            )}
          </PopoverButton>
        </div>

Above is my HTML structure and below is the code for the media query when users browse on small screens.
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false babelPresetReact: false babelPresetTS: false -->

    @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
      .menu-link {
        display: none;
      }

      .mobile {
        display: inherit;
        justify-content: left;
        margin-left: -10rem;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .mobile {
        display: inherit;
        margin-left: -2rem;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
      .mobile {
        justify-content: end;
      }
    }


Here is what it looks like locally, everything is loaded and seems to be working fine: 
Here is what it looks like on Vercel (after being uploaded through GitHub) and we can see parts are missing: 

have you used dev tools to check if CSS is actually loaded or ignored?

On the dev tools, the query is not showing there and the sm:hidden is taking effect instead of my custom query https://snipboard.io/UuoEfK.jpg

Using tailwind and vanilla css is not best practice, try to use one of them ( recommended is tailwind ). Still you want to use both then use !important with vanilla css which will overwrite tailwind and apply vanilla css.

@JuryGregorio I already knew that, what I meant is do you see if the custom css actually reached the browser and got overriden or not. Take a screenshot of all the styles, even the overriden ones


@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .menu-link {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobile {
    display: inherit;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-left: -10rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mobile {
    display: inherit;
    margin-left: -2rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
  .mobile {
    justify-content: end;
  }
}


There is no difference to the code in the question (?), and no explanation either

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
